# Add new key with value = NULL to existing JSON object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following simple JSON object:

```js
{
    "application": {
        "status": "XXX"
    }
}
```

I'd like to add a new key under application called "approve_date" and would like the value to be NULL. Is there a way to do this with `JSON_MODIFY`. I tried using 'append' in the path but this added an array, not a key (example below).

```sql
JSON_MODIFY(data, 'append $.application.approve_date', null)
```

What is the better way to (A) add a new key to the JSON and (B) make it a NULL value?

Comment: isn't the definition of a null value that the key does not exist?

Comment: Post the expected output.

Comment: @ittiekat do you mean `{"application":
       {"status":"XXX"},{"approve_date":null}
}` ?

Comment: expected output is {"application":{"status":"XXX","approve_date":null}}

Comment: unfortunately in this case, I need the key to exist and be null.  omitting the key entirely causes a different issue for what i'm doing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using [`JSON_MODIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) with `NULL` as the new value, the behavior depends on mode (see documentation).

One *trick* is to use a combination of lax mode (to add a key) and strict mode (to set its value to null).

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_MODIFY(
        JSON_MODIFY(
            '{"application":{"status":"XXX"}}',
            'lax $.application.approve_date',
            ''
        ), -- {"application":{"status":"XXX","approve_date":""}}
        'strict $.application.approve_date',
        NULL
    ) -- {"application":{"status":"XXX","approve_date":null}}
```